# CloudKit WatchOS throwing "CloudKit access was denied by user settings"

Tags: watchkit, cloudkit

I have made an app that makes use of CloudKit. One user has recently reported the app to be crashing whenever he uses the feature that interacts with CloudKit. I was able to pin down the issue on him not having enabled "iCloud Drive" in the iCloud settings.

After enabling it, the iPhone app has stopped crashing for him - however on the Watch, whenever it tries to fetch a `CKRecord`, he is getting the same error message all the time:
`CloudKit access was denied by user settings`
What else can cause this? The app doesn't have a lot of users but no one so far has reported this issue. Is there a possibility that Apple hasn't thought of syncing this setting with the Watch?